# Bio of Donald A. Wollheim

Tags: authors, editors, donald-a-wollheim

Donald A. Wollheim was a very influential science fiction and fantasy editor. There is a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_A._Wollheim) about him, but it lacks almost any biographical information. There is nothing, for example, about

- his family's economic status, how they made a living, or whether they were immigrants;
- his education, politics, or religion, or those of his family;
- whether he had any jobs before becoming a full-time writer and editor, or how economically successful he was;
- how he died;
- whether he had any other interests;
- and so on.

Basically I'm not getting any picture whatsoever of him as a person. Isfdb has a [page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?826) on him, but the bio is blank.

**Can anyone give any info or any kind of sketch of him as a person?**

Answer (score 18):

I am the daughter of Donald A. Wollheim and have written an extensive biographical article about him. It was published in Leigh Grossman's SENSE OF WONDER: A CENTURY OF SCIENCE FICTION.
This is the article:

### Donald A. Wollheim: The Uncompromising Visionary

My father was an extreme man: extremely intelligent, extremely well read, and with extreme opinions that he voiced in extremely direct and sometimes brutal ways. He was also moody—in turn philosophical, light-hearted and funny, buoyed by childlike enthusiasm, then darkly depressed, bitter, and angry. He was an extreme man, but never a boring one. It is my belief that the extremes of his personality, combined with his visionary intellect were the keys to his extraordinary achievements in the publishing industry and specifically, in the science fiction and fantasy field.

When I was very young, Don was a wonderful father to me. He read to me for an hour every night as I sat in his lap in the large padded rocker in the library of our home in Queens. He read me the complete works of L. Frank Baum, the poems of A.A. Milne, Andrew Lang’s Colored Fairy Books, and many more wondrous old volumes that he allowed me to choose from the gargoyle-covered Victorian glass-front bookcases in our basement. But though I was a child, he didn’t always read me children’s books. Sometimes he read poetry. Vachel Lindsay was one of his favorites because of the cadences and rhythms. He taught me to love the sound of words—even the sound of words I didn’t understand—words that his beautifully deep and sonorous reading voice made sound like music.

Don could be difficult, but he was my dad, and I understood him in a way that was more intuitive than logical. The closeness I felt for him as a child bolstered me in later years, during times when our relationship was stormy.

Don took me to my first science fiction convention when I was six. Perhaps it was there that I began to notice how people responded to him. Later, as a preteen, I saw that certain people were completely simpatico and easygoing with Don, others seemed intimidated by him, yet others seemed merely awkward in his presence, and still others were plainly in awe and even seemed to idolize him.

Marion Zimmer Bradley, who first worked with Don at Ace Books in 1958, seemed completely oblivious to the character traits that inspired fear in others. She used to come into his office at DAW, pull a chair up to the opposite side of his desk, put her elbows down, and they would talk for hours. I remember her saying to him: “I want to write a circus book.” He responded: “Bad idea! Bad idea!” Many authors would have given up at that point, but not Marion: She banged her fist on Don’s desk and said “But I WANT to!” And as a result, he reneged: “Well, okay then!”

When Marion was writing The Mists of Avalon for Lester Del Rey, she would often come to my father’s office directly from Lester’s and throw herself across Don’s desk shaking with sobs. “He keeps telling me to make it deeper—how many times can I make it deeper?” But both Marion and Don knew that Lester was right. Marion had always been a first draft author, but this magnum opus required more. So Don offered Marion comfort while she wrote her greatest work for one of his competitors.

But no author bonded with my father as closely as C.J. Cherryh. For nearly ten years, she was like a second daughter, and whenever she was in town, she stayed at our home in Queens, and they were inseparable. It was common to see them leaning across the kitchen table, heads together, engrossed in intense discussion. Despite a Masters from Johns Hopkins, a history of world travel, and being a multi-lingual classics teacher, Carolyn seemed almost pathologically shy to me in the early days. There were times I spent with her when she could be silent for hours on end. But with my dad, she became an animated conversationalist, another person completely.

Don had a talent for making people angry, but many of them were too intimidated to confront him directly. Sometimes I became the target instead, which wasn't exactly appropriate (especially since some of these attacks occurred when I was just a teenager) but was nonetheless indicative of the dysfunctional familial nature of the science fiction field. Certain professionals in the industry attacked me for wrongs perceived by them to have been perpetrated by my dad. Most of these “wrongs” had occurred long before I became a professional myself, and I knew nothing about them. Other times, I could deduce what had occurred, and sometimes I thought Don was right and sometimes I thought he was wrong, but either way I felt honor bound to defend the father I loved and admired.

I was used numerous times by a prominent west coast author with a penchant for grandstanding as a vehicle to attack my parents publicly at science fiction conventions. This man liked to silence crowded rooms by loudly pointing me out and exclaiming over how amazing it was that I had survived and flourished in the home of my parents, despite being raised by “that horrible alta kocker, her father.” He would then go on to flamboyantly insult one or both of my parents on personal, professional or ethical grounds. My father, when he heard of one of these incidents, just laughed and said: “It is one of the great mysteries of the science fiction world how [that author] can depict such sensitive characters while being such a boor himself.” My father was not the bit least upset. I’m not entirely sure why this author, who did not seem easily intimidated, attacked my parents through their adolescent daughter so many times. Perhaps he had tried attacking my father directly and not gotten the reaction he was hoping for. Or perhaps he was intimidated after all.

When I was attacked on his behalf, it was always when Don wasn’t there to defend himself or his point of view. I was hearing only the complainant’s side of the story, usually delivered quite aggressively. Ironic, since these individuals chose not to confront Don himself.  I was once harangued by an artist when my father was in the same room, though out of hearing. “Your father had no right!” he shouted repeatedly. Though I pointed out that perhaps he should take his complaints to my dad, and that he was “standing right over there,” he ignored my suggestion and continued to yell at me.

That so many people went out of their way to avoid a confrontation with my father speaks resoundingly of the power of words to hurt, and also of my father’s unwillingness to compromise or soften his opinion for any reason whatsoever.  My dad sold his first short story, The Man From Ariel, in 1934, to Wonder Stories, when he was just nineteen. When the ten dollars he was promised for the story never came,  my dad got together with several other authors and successfully sued the publisher—Hugo Gernsback—settling for the hefty sum of $75.  Despite having made his point and received the money he was owed, he then submitted a story to Gernsback under a pseudonym, and once again, didn't get paid. (He was expelled from Gernsback’s New York Science Fiction League as "a disruptive influence" but was later reinstated.) It was a pretty ballsy act for a young author to sue the man who first put him into print. But that’s how my dad was.

He had a proclivity for inflammatory language and loved single syllable words like “crap,” “trash,” and “junk.” These words can be very wounding, especially when wielded authoritatively by a man of letters. Such words don’t even criticize; they judge and then discount completely. Highly litigious, prone to feuding, and always up for a fight, my dad was as unlike Mahatma Gandhi as a man could be, yet he believed Gandhi’s statement that, “A ‘No’ uttered from deepest conviction is better and greater than a ‘Yes’ merely uttered to please, or what is worse, to avoid trouble.”

In a letter to my mother dated January 28, 1942 (the year before they were married) Don describes his moodiness:

> I am subject to waves of moods …. There are times, you surely must have noted, when I am happy and full of wit and laughter. And other times when I am sober and depressed. You have seen me coldly impersonally analytical, cynical, aloof. And you have recently seen me in an emotional storm. There are times when I am quite alone in the world and everything else is stomach-wrenching rot. And times when I feel as one with a universal wave of humanity….

He knew who he was, and the way he describes himself in his late 20s is a valid description of how he was his entire life.

When he died, I read through article after article written about my dad, and I was surprised by how few people mentioned his personality. I believe it was partly because of his personality that he was able to achieve as much as he did. He was completely self motivated. He could be hurt emotionally and professionally by people’s negative opinions, yet these opinions would never sway his actions. He did what he believed was right, and damn the torpedoes. He was an uncompromising idealist who believed in meritocracy. He felt he should get recognition for his achievements, not for his popularity or lack thereof. His personality did not lend itself to acts of social lubrication. He was not a schmoozer, and although indisputably one of the greatest editors in the history of science fiction publishing—some say the greatest—he was never awarded a Best Editor Hugo. He was deeply hurt by that.

There were some people, however, who saw through his brittle exterior to the person he was inside. Robert Silverberg, in his essay on my father in Reflections and Refractions: Thoughts on Science Fiction, Science and Other Matters, (Underwood Books, 1997) said:

> In person he could be difficult: abrasive and passionately opinionated, a fierce ideological combatant, a vehement holder of grudges.  Behind the abrasiveness, though, he was actually a shy and likable man, as his long-time friends can attest; but that wasn’t always readily apparent to outsiders.

He was a visionary, a person who could see things that had not yet come to pass and imagine what they could be in the future, and he was never loathe to take a controversial stance. Because of these qualities he was often at the forefront of emerging trends, in and around publishing.

He founded and edited one of the earliest fanzines, The Phantograph, and in 1935, at the age of twenty-one, engaged in an avid correspondence with H. P. Lovecraft. I still have eight letters and two postcards from Lovecraft to my father. Lovecraft’s tiny, cramped cursive is barely legible. In one letter dated July 6, 1936, the great master tells my father that he has verified the suicide of Robert E. Howard, the author of the Conan novels, and says, “The loss to weird fiction is staggering.” Included in this letter is Lovecraft’s hand-written obituary for publication in The Phantagraph.

With this same strength of vision, Don edited two of the earliest science fiction pulp magazines, Cosmic Stories, and Stirring Science Stories with no pay and no budget—stories were willingly contributed by friends. He also organized the first science fiction convention in October, 1936 (today’s Philcon claims descent from this very first convention), formed one of the earliest sf clubs, The Futurians, in 1938, and in 1943, edited the first paperback science fiction anthology, The Pocket Book of Science Fiction. He told me of a young sf writer who would occasionally hang out with the Futurian crowd in Brooklyn and "brag that he was going to invent a new religion based on science and make a million dollars." That writer, who was L. Ron Hubbard, vastly underestimated his future financial outlook.

One of the pioneer paperback editors at Avon Books from 1947-1951— for two of those years, the only paperback editor—Don not only worked on novels, but also on the Avon Fantasy Reader. At Avon he introduced the works of A. Merritt, the science fiction of C. S. Lewis, the stories of H. P. Lovecraft, the novels of Robert E. Howard, and countless others, to a wider readership, and in the Avon Fantasy Reader, published stories by many newcomers, including Ray Bradbury.  In 1949, Don  edited the very first all-original science fiction anthology, The Girl With the Hungry Eyes.

In 1952, when he left Avon to become the startup editor of a new paperback list for the Ace Magazine Company, he really hit his stride. He brought the double novel—two short novels, bound back to back in the same volume with two front covers—into the sphere of paperback books. In this modest Ace Double format Don was able to introduce many great new writers by pairing them with more established names. These new writers included Philip K.Dick, Samuel R. Delany, Ursula K. Le Guin, Harlan Ellison, Robert Silverberg, and Brian W. Aldiss. Although Don’s great love was science fiction, at Ace Books he edited multiple genres, and introduced great works beyond the sf world. It was in the pages of an Ace Double that William S. Burroughs (under the pseudonym “William Lee”) first published Junkie, bound with an anti-drug pamphlet. I’ve heard that Burroughs’ original title was “Junk,” but my father argued that it would be mistaken for a book about trash and suggested its final title.

While at Ace, Don published Andre Norton, Marion Zimmer Bradley, Roger Zelazny, Poul Anderson, R. A. Lafferty, Gordon R. Dickson, Fritz Leiber, Jack Vance, A.E. van Vogt, and many others. He also reprinted many great works in paperback, including Asimov’s Foundation series, Frank Herbert’s Dune (which he was afraid would be mistaken for a Western because of its title),  the work of Edgar Rice Burroughs, and others too numerous to list. He pursued his love of short fiction by initiating the very first best-of-the-year anthologies: World’s Best Science Fiction, in 1965, with co-editor Terry Carr. Perhaps his greatest achievement at Ace, however, was also considered by many to be his most notorious: the unauthorized paperback reprinting of Tolkien’s Lord of the Rings. This brazen act, which was undoubtedly the “big bang” that gave birth to the entire modern fantasy genre, spawned years of dark clouds over the dinner table, due to vilification of my father by the newly risen hordes of Tolkien worshipers who the Oxford don himself referred to as “despicable cultists.”

My dad was also a writer, and published eighteen novels, two full length works of nonfiction, and nearly a hundred short stories. But in true Don fashion, he was as harsh a critic of his own work as he was of others’, and accurately categorized himself as a “fair to middling” writer. He knew that his real talents lay in the editorial realm. Ironically, he stubbornly refused to let his own work be edited.

---

My father grew up in a very cold, formal household. Don’s father, Dr. Jacob Lewis Wollheim, was a urologist who specialized in venereal disease. Grandpa Wollheim practiced out of the second floor of the family’s brownstone in Manhattan, and my father and his sister had to walk through the medical offices to reach their bedrooms. Specializing in a field that treated two very common, but at the time incurable, diseases—syphilis and gonorrhea—he was terrified that his children would touch an infected surface in his office, put a finger in a mouth, nose, or eye, and contract a version of one of these terrible diseases. This was a very real concern, and because of my grandfather’s efforts to protect his children, my father grew to be a man who did not like to be kissed or touched.

In a letter written to my mother in 1942, he describes the nature of his childhood home: “Outsiders notice very rapidly that in the smooth, formal, surface normality of my household there are terrible tides that are sensed rather than seen. Once, a cousin of mine…lived with us for a period. After six months she moved. She said that she could not stand the chill cold formality of things.” And later in the same letter: “When you live in a family that is eternally at war within itself, a child must find some defense to save his mind.” Clearly for my father that defense lay in the escapist realm of imaginary fiction. He became a compulsive reader.

My dad was damaged neurologically and for a long time didn’t know why. As a boy he was physically unable to participate in sports—he could not catch a ball because his left hand wouldn’t respond in time. He was a loner, a bookworm, disinclined to be social. Shy and self-conscious, his severe acne and large buck teeth didn’t help. When he was thirty-five, he finally looked into his own medical file in his father’s office and discovered he had contracted polio in the epidemic of 1918 and, at age four, had been paralyzed for six months. After this discovery, memories began to surface: being carried down the back stairs of the house by his governess and put in a highchair in the sunny backyard, feeling angry because he was too old to be in a highchair. He remembered the house was dark during the day because his father insisted that the shades stay down.

Irrational as it was, my grandfather was ashamed that his son—the son of an acclaimed physician—had contracted polio. He somehow believed that he should have been able to protect his family, even from an epidemic. When Don recovered, his left leg was slightly shorter than his right, giving him the distinctive swaying limp that characterized his gait for the rest of his life. My grandfather had kept this secret, believing his son might otherwise develop an “invalid mentality”—common thinking at the time. And in some ways, it worked, but I have no doubt that Don was deeply traumatized by being left without an explanation for so many years for the physical abnormalities that he saw as shortcomings. It did, however, set him on a solitary but innovative path.

Don was a rebel: a Communist in his father’s Republican household, a science fiction writer and pulp magazine editor living in a very formal, in some ways still Edwardian, doctor’s home in a world that had never heard the term “science fiction.”

It’s ironic that he came to be known as The Dean of old school science fiction when he was  such a staunchly determined advocate of the new. How odd that he was seen as a bastion of the old-fashioned when he had conceived and been at the forefront of so many new things: science fiction fandom and conventions, pulp magazines, and the birth of the paperback book. My father was considered old school partly because he was an arch idealist. For him science fiction was an intrinsically optimistic genre because it said: there will be a future. Although he loved H.G. Wells, my dad disapproved of modern dystopian near-future science fiction. Don was a lifelong literary romantic.

In a letter dated June 9, 1941, Don defended his unconventional choice of careers to his father:

> When you became a doctor, you had to go through two or three years of unpaying and fruitless work…. This that I am going through is not actually different. These magazines may fold up or they may succeed. But this period, which may last a year and may even last longer, is something I must go through. An editor is a professional man—actually that.
>
> I am carefully engaged in working on my own magazines—I am determined to make these magazines the very best on the market, and I might say that from the expressed opinions of the science fiction fans (the experts) I do now publish the second best—second out of a field of fourteen!
>
> And consider…I am making this high mark in the very lowest budget and under the most difficult conditions of any fantasy pulp magazine published today….
>
> As a science-fictionist, as a writer, as an editor, I have hundreds of friends and admirers all over the country. To them, Wollheim is a name of strength and pride. I do not think that I have used my name wrongly.

In this letter he expresses his total dedication to the world of writing and editing science fiction and his belief that his choice of profession would one day provide him with an appropriate income.

By 1971, Ace Books had been sold and was being mismanaged.  The situation had become intolerable for my dad. He realized that if he didn’t leave, his reputation would be compromised. Without warning, or the knowledge of anyone but my mother, he simply walked off the job, turning his back on the list he thought of as his. Abandoning Ace nearly broke his heart, and Don was without work for the first time since 1940. After a tense few months—months when I returned from college to find my dad suffering bouts of dizziness and shortness of breath—he came home from a meeting with New American Library exuberant, and told us, “They said I could come to them any way I want!” On the basis of his reputation alone, NAL let him write his own ticket. He formed a new company devoted exclusively to science fiction and fantasy, the first of its kind. After weeks of debate with mom and me at the kitchen table, he named it after himself: DAW.

He also made a momentous decision at this time—a decision that proved critical to the success of his new enterprise: he hired my mom to be his business manager. My mom had both legal and business experience, and threw herself behind DAW with unbridled enthusiasm. Only 4-foot 11 at her absolute tallest, and four years older than Don, nonetheless Elsie was exactly what my dad needed: she was warm, compulsively social, and fiercely protective of our authors. Tad Williams called her “the iron hummingbird,” and Marion Zimmer Bradley said, “Elsie has the spirit of a lion in the body of a sparrow.”

When DAW was founded, my dad was fifty-seven, and he thought of his new company as a retirement job. After all, he only had to work on the genre he loved the most, and he had a small list—six titles a month. At Ace, he had been personally responsible for twenty-two books a month.

The fourteen years that he ran DAW were some of the happiest years of his life.

At DAW, Don published many of the same authors he had worked with at Ace and continued to introduce new authors: C. J. Cherryh, Tanith Lee, Tad Williams, C. S. Friedman, Michael Shea, and more. Since 1985, I’ve run DAW with my business partner Sheila Gilbert. With our workloads in mind, we derive endless entertainment from thinking of DAW as a “retirement job.”

Despite difficult times, I could never imagine another father giving me as much as Don gave me. Not only did I inherit his editorial abilities, I inherited his love of words and of the genre, and I inherited a publishing company.  I would never, in a million years, wish for a different father.
Betsy Wollheim, New York City, January 31, 2011

Comment: This is a great story, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Just to clarify: is your entire answer the text of the article that was published?

Answer (score 12):

I found this bio pretty easily, and I've taken the liberty of bolding the portions that seem especially insightful in regard to his life.

> (1914-1990) US editor and writer, and one of the first and most vociferous Science Fiction fans; with Forrest J Ackerman, Wollheim was perhaps the most dynamic member of the embryo Fandom of the 1930s. **A lifetime resident of New York City**, he published innumerable Fanzines, was co-editor of the early semiprozine Fanciful Tales of Time and Space in 1936, **founded the Fantasy Amateur Press Association (FAPA), and was one of the founders in 1938 of the Futurians**, becoming deeply involved in its pursuits and feuds. **His long-standing quarrel with James Blish began at this time**; he does not mention Blish in his anecdotal History of Science Fiction, The Universe Makers: Science Fiction Today (1971), whose premises reflect 1930s enthusiasm about Science Fiction as an form of advocacy of a science- and Technology-driven history (see Future Histories). As carried over into a the 1970s, this pattern of conviction clearly fuelled **his comments on the negative effects of the New Wave on the Genre Science Fiction to which he remained patriotically loyal** (see Optimism and Pessimism). The long-held mutual animosity between Wollheim and Blish was also partially rooted in differences that could be sourced in Politics, though in their case more explicitly than surfaced **in his expressions of disavowal in 1971, for in the years before World War Two Wollheim clearly stood far to the left of the spectrum** and Blish clearly stood far to the right. Aspects of his role and the positions he took are reflected in his Operation Phantasy: The Best from the Phantagraph (anth 1967 chap), a collection of early fanzine material; **his part in early fandom was also extensively chronicled in The Immortal Storm** (essays 1945-1953 Fantasy Commentator; incomplete version 1951 mimeograph; full version 1954) by Sam Moskowitz, and in The Futurians (1977) by Damon Knight.
>
> Wollheim's first published story was "The Man from Ariel" for Wonder Stories in January 1934 (for which **Hugo Gernsback notoriously did not pay him until threatened with court action**), but he did not begin to publish fiction with any regularity until the 1940s. For his short stories he often used the pseudonyms Millard Verne Gordon and Martin Pearson, as well as the collaborative pseudonyms Arthur Cooke and Lawrence Woods; two solo stories appeared as by Allen Warland. As Pearson he published the story "Mimic" (December 1942 Astonishing Stories) – filmed Mimic (1997) – and the Ajax Calkins series which later formed the basis of his novel Destiny's Orbit (1962) as by David Grinnell, sequelled by Destination: Saturn (1967) as by Grinnell with Lin Carter. Wollheim's fiction in the 1950s and 1960s divided into adult novels as by David Grinnell, none being any more remarkable than the Calkins sequence; and Children's Science Fiction published under his own name. The Mike Mars series of children's books, efficiently exploring different facets of the space programme, was popular; it comprised Mike Mars, Astronaut (1961), Mike Mars Flies the X-15 (1961), Mike Mars at Cape Canaveral (1961; vt Mike Mars at Cape Kennedy 1966), Mike Mars in Orbit (1961), Mike Mars Flies the Dyna-Soar (1962), Mike Mars, South Pole Spaceman (1962), Mike Mars and the Mystery Satellite (1963) and Mike Mars around the Moon (1964). The stand-alone The Secret of the Ninth Planet (1959) features a melodramatic tour of the solar system whose ultimate destination is Pluto (see Outer Planets).
>
> By the beginning of the 1940s, however, fiction began to become a useful sideline, for **Wollheim had already embarked on his editorial career' which would become his major (and justified) claim to pre-eminence in the Science Fiction field**. In 1941 he was made editor of Cosmic Stories and Stirring Science Stories, both of which he produced creditably on a minute budget, publishing many stories by his fellow Futurians (most prolifically C M Kornbluth). He also compiled two pioneering Science Fiction Anthologies: The Pocket Book of Science Fiction (anth 1943) – the first book to contain the words "science fiction" in its title – and Portable Novels of Science (anth 1945). After World War Two he worked for Avon Books (1947-1952), for whom he edited the Avon Fantasy Reader and the Avon Science Fiction Reader series [which we treat in this encyclopedia as comprising both magazine- and Anthology-like characteristics; see Checklist, therefore, for titles]; as well as Out of This World Adventures, 10 Story Fantasy and, uncredited, the first Science Fiction Original Anthology, The Girl with the Hungry Eyes and Other Stories (anth 1949). **He subsequently moved from Avon to Ace Books in 1952, where he created and for the next twenty years ran one of the two or three most dominant US Science Fiction lists of those decades**, the others being Ballantine Books and Doubleday; he won a 1964 Hugo for his work.
>
> Taking advantage of the Ace Double Novel format (see Dos-à-Dos), he published the first or very early works of many writers who later achieved fame, including Marion Zimmer Bradley, John Brunner, Samuel R Delany, Philip K Dick, Thomas M Disch, Harlan Ellison, Ursula K Le Guin, Robert Silverberg and Roger Zelazny, though the bulk of the list was cannily built around colourful Science Fiction adventures with a strong emphasis on Space Opera; **his piracy of J R R Tolkien's Lord of the Rings in 1965 may have been sharp practice, but was clearly instrumental in making Tolkien a household name by the end of that decade**. By 1970, however, the Ace list had begun to fade seriously, though it is clear in hindsight (see discussion of DAW Books below) that the firm – under new ownership with controversial accountancy principles ensuring the non-payment of authors except upon demand – had begun to drift; he himself had lost nothing of his acumen. During the 1950s he also worked editorially on the magazines Orbit and Saturn, and edited a great many anthologies, often for Ace; these included such theme collections as The End of the World (anth 1956), Men on the Moon (anth 1958 dos; exp 1969) and The Hidden Planet (anth 1959), the latter being of stories set on Venus. There were many more [see Checklist] until the 1970s.
>
> In 1971, **Wollheim left Ace and in 1972 he founded DAW Books, which he continued to run until 1985, when ill-health induced him to appoint his daughter, Betsy Wollheim (1954- ) as president**. With his new firm, he began almost immediately to loosen the format and content constraints that had increasingly plagued his later career at Ace: series were emphasized heavily; old-style Space Opera gave way to Planetary Romance; authors like C J Cherryh and Tanith Lee, who were comfortable with Science Fantasy, were strongly encouraged; and he allowed authors like M A Foster very considerable latitude (compared with his days at Ace) to experiment, and to explore moderately Taboo areas (John Norman moved over from Ballantine Books, presumably to take advantage of this liberty) and to write at very varying lengths. **Though he continued not to pay well enough to retain best-selling authors, he kept his firm healthy and active for the remaining years of his career**.
>
> **In 1965, Wollheim had begun to issue an annual "year's best" anthology, World's Best Science Fiction; this continued until the end of his life in an unbroken yearly succession, although there was some highly confusing retitling, occasioned in part by his shift from Ace to DAW Books**. The first phase of the sequence began with World's Best Science Fiction: 1965 (anth 1965; vt World's Best Science Fiction: First Series 1970) with Terry Carr, and ended with World's Best Science Fiction: 1971 (anth 1971) with Terry Carr (who served as co-editor for all intervening volumes as well). After the switch to DAW, the sequence continued with The 1972 Annual World's Best Science Fiction (anth 1972; vt Wollheim's World's Best Science Fiction: Series One 1977) with Arthur W Saha, ending with The 1990 Annual World's Best Science Fiction (anth 1990) with Arthur W Saha (who served as co-editor for all intervening volumes as well). [For all titles see Checklist.]
>
> **For fifty years Wollheim remained one of the most important editorial influences on Science Fiction, and in his later years – despite his very well known capacity to carry on disputes half a century old – he became a revered figure. His death marked – as clearly as those of Isaac Asimov and Robert A Heinlein – the passing of the generation of the founders**. He was posthumously inducted into the Science Fiction Hall of Fame in 2002. [JC/MJE]
> [Science Fiction Encyclopedia](http://www.Sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/wollheim_donald_a#sthash.ZKnLtGXv.dpuf)

A second article:

> Between the heyday of the pulp magazines and dedicated science-fiction novels came a transition in how people consumed their science fiction. The magazine market began to wane as technological improvements made it easier to cheaply print paperback novels. As authors shifted from writing short fiction for magazines to longer fiction for books, they began to collect their shorter stories into longer narratives. The result was a “Fix-Up” novel, a term coined by van Vogt, and was merely a short-gap measure in a rapidly changing publishing environment.
>
> In the post-war environment, paperback novels began to gain traction in the marketplace, and publishers and readers began to gravitate toward the books. In 1942, founding Futurian member Donald A. Wollheim was hired at Pocket Books and shifted gears from editing short fiction to editing paperback novels. There, he edited and published the first ever paperback science fiction anthology, The Pocket Book of Science Fiction. In 1947, he left Pocket Books for Avon Books, where he manned their entire editorial department. He spent the next five years miserable with his position, and began to look for other work, approaching publisher Aaron A. Wyn, who was starting up a company dedicated to publishing paperback novels.
>
> Wyn got his start editing pulp magazines and hardcover novels before moving into the paperback business. He was interested in what Wollheim had to say, but failed to move quickly: A dedicated publisher of genre paperback novels was a new concept. Frustrated with the delay, Wollheim moved on to interview with Pyramid Books for another editorial position. Following his meeting, the company mistakenly called Wyn’s wife, Rose, for a reference. The call prompted Wyn to action, and he hired Wollheim immediately. Together, in 1952, they founded Ace Books.
>
> From the start, Ace began an innovative approach to their novels by printing them Tête-bêche style. Each volume contained two short novels, with a book on each side, flipped 180 degrees from the other. A reader would pick up one book, read through it, and flip the book to read the other. Wollheim and Wyn began with publishing two double novels a month: one Western and the other a mystery.
>
> In October 1953, Ace introduced its first science-fiction novel, pairing up two novels from A.E. van Vogt: The World of Null-A and The Universe Maker. Every other month, a new book would appear on the book rack. Van Vogt’s book was followed in December 1953 by Robert E. Howard’s Conan the Conqueror and Leigh Brackett’s The Sword of Rhiannon. In between, the company published a single novel. Due to their popularity, Ace bumped the production schedule up to a science-fiction double a month in 1958.
>
> At the price of $0.35 a book (the price would eventually increase to $0.95 per volume in the 21 years that the doubles would be published), Wollheim was able to introduce an incredible range of talent. In the time in which the double novels were published, Ace would publish authors such as Brian Aldiss, Poul Anderson, Isaac Asimov, Philip K. Dick, Gordon R. Dickson, James E. Gunn, Andre Norton, Margaret St. Clair, Robert Silverberg, Jack Vance and hundreds of other authors. Often, a well-known author would be paired up with a newcomer, such as Philip K. Dick, with his first novel The Solar Lottery, who was paired up with Leigh Brackett and her novel The Big Jump. The format helped to increase the visibility of new authors, helping to launch a number of careers in the field. In the 1960s, Ace continued to expand into the science-fiction market, hiring Terry Carr, who introduced the popular Ace Science-Fiction Specials line of novels. Ace began publishing J.R.R. Tolkien’s Lord of the Rings trilogy in 1965, citing a copyright loophole, and faced a backlash when Tolkien called for a boycott of the unauthorized editions.
>
> Still, while Ace had a successful product on their hands, authors found the publisher problematic to work with. Constrained by the limits of paper and glue, the novels were short, with the entire volume rarely breaking 100,000 words. As a result, many authors often found that the released versions of their stories were significantly edited for length. Authors such as Isaac Asimov and John Brunner noted their outrage at the unauthorized butchering of their novels, which often impacted the stories that they were trying to tell.
>
> Ace’s fortunes had begun to decline. In 1967, A.A. Wyn passed away, and by this time the company, now owned by Charter Communications, had run into considerable financial problems after several mainstream novels failed. Authors rarely received an advance of more than $1,500 per novel, and faced delays in actually receiving their money. Now, with money running short, Wollheim found himself unable to pay for new manuscripts, and began to reissue older novels. One author, Ron Goulart, found that the royalties from one of his novels (Clockwork’s Pirates and Ghostbreaker), was greater than the other, despite both books being bound together in the same volume. Another auAce Double Novelthor’s book was sent to the printer without a signed contract: He was forced into manual labor to make ends meet.
>
> Frustrated with the turn that Ace had taken, Wollheim and Carr left Ace in 1971. Hired to replace Wollheim, Frederic Pohl left after eight months after facing the same situation as his predecessor. Free from Ace, Wollheim set up a new company, DAW Books, co-published by New American Library, which began publishing in April 1972. In August 1973, Ace discontinued the Ace Doubles brand, ending an era of science-fiction paperbacks. Ultimately, Ace was sold to Grosset & Dunlap in 1976, improving the state of the publisher and returning it to profitability. Ace Books is one of the oldest science-fiction publishers in the United States and is now an imprint of the Penguin Group alongside another genre imprint, Roc Books.
>
> Ace’s Double Novels were a distinctive part of the science-fiction community throughout the two decades in which they were published. The line helped to launch the novel careers of a number of authors, from Philip K. Dick to Ursula K. Le Guin to Samuel R. Delany, in addition to a number of other popular authors in the field, such as A.E. van Vogt, Margaret St. Clair and Leigh Brackett. Long out of print, the books can still be found at conventions and might seem like nostalgic relics of the past. However, the books were an innovative entry in a brand-new publishing world, one that found both considerable staying power and a platform for publishing a high volume of science fiction. The huge number of stories published allowed for something great to happen: Talented authors with interesting stories to tell broke into the field, allowing for their own voices to shape the genre as they continued to find success. Like the pulp magazines that preceded them, the Ace Doubles had their own lasting impact on the future of the genre.
> [Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/features/donald-wollheim-and-ace-double-novel/#continue_reading_post)

Comment: For a different aspect of his life, see the Fancyclopedia 3 entry: http://fancyclopedia.org/donald-a-wollheim

Answer (score -5):

I do know that he was very prominent in early science fiction fandom and was a founder of the famous Futurian Society in New York City.

Any history of science fiction fandom is bound to have some mention of him.

[1](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/Entry/wollheim_donald_a)http://sf-encyclopedia.com/Entry/wollheim_donald_a

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment than an answer

Comment: The above article has two glaring errors. I was born in 1951, not 1954 (though I appreciate being cited as younger!) and the 1964 Hugo was to Ace Books, not my dad. My dad never won a Hugo, not even a Retro Hugo.
Betsy